# WPF DataGridCell styling CurrentItem

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Is there a way to trigger style on a current row/item?
If only one row is selected, this

```
<Trigger Property="DataGridCell.IsSelected" Value="True">
```

works, but what if more then one row is selcted. I only want to style the cells/rowheaders, that belong to the current item.

Comment: What item is current in your opinion?

Comment: DataGrid.CurrentItem: The line that you get when you call CurrentItem on the DataGrid object.

Answer (score 1):

With "cells that belong to the current item" I guess you mean the currently focused row?
There are two different types of "selections".
One is the selection it self (indicated by the `IsSelected` property), which indicates the selection of the `DataGrid`. That means, every row that is selected (or only one single, if you don't allow multiple).
The second is the focused cell or row (indicated by the `IsFocused` property), which is not used for the data behavior of the grid, but for the graphical selection, or, as you call it, the "current" row or cell.

There are several properties you can use:

```
<Style x:Key="cellstyle" TargetType="DataGridCell">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

The first changes **every** selected cell (if you select them by holding the shift key). The second changes only the "current" cell.

If you need to do this for the whole row of the "current" cell, you could do so with the `IsKeyboardFocusWithin` property of the row:

```
<Style x:Key="rowstyle" TargetType="DataGridRow">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Purple" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

The example above demonstrates how to add behaviors to the whole row. Note that the cell background is always in front of the row backround. If you need to have both, cell and row backgrounds (so you can't work with transparent cell backgrounds) you need to use `MultiDataBinding`, where you exclude the according row state. Lets say, a condition that needs the `IsKeyboardFocusWithin` of the row to be false:

```
<MultiDataTrigger>
    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=IsKeyboardFocusWithin, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}}" Value="False"/>
        <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}" Value="True"/>
    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
</MultiDataTrigger>
```

Don't forget that, when you have multiple trigger that are true, the last within the list is taken. This means, if you'd change the order of the triggers in the first example, you wouldn't see any difference from selected to focused cell.

Comment: Coloring the whole row is what I want, but the trigger (IsKeyboardFocusWithin) is not working for me. At least not on DataGridRow. On DataGridCell it does.

Comment: When I set the cell's Background to Transparent, I see the styled row, but then I don't see the selection highlighting.

Comment: Ok I updated the post with an example to exclude row conditions on the cell style. Don't forget, that you can only work with direct property names in condtions of `MultiBinding` and only with bindings in conditions of `MultiDataBinding`.